# TextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar doesnt keep value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've tried to make password column in dataGridView by simply changing UseSystemPasswordChar attribute of every Control with ColumnIndex of 3:

```
void grid_EditingControlShowing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (grid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 3)
    {
        (grid.EditingControl as TextBox).UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
    }
}
```

But when cell loses focus, attribute value turns into "false" again.
Why is that happening?

Comment: I think the grid is re-creating the edit control every time the cell goes into editing mode.

Comment: Seems true. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`CurrentCell` reports which cell has the focus.  So in your failure case no cell has focus, and therefore your setting never takes place.
Is the value cleared somewhere else in your code?

Comment: No, I dont clear value, btw I just found that every TextBox cell changes to "Password" style, not only cells of fourth column.